# How to give a constant function scope in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I want to know how to define a constant whose scope is limited to a function.

```
def foo(number)
   # I want this to be a constant defined only inside foo
   ABC = 123 
   return number * 123
end
```

Comment: IIRC constants don't work like that. What's the purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this.  The code above will give a `dynamic constant assignment` error, because there's nothing to ensure that `foo()` is only called once.  Ruby constants aren't really constant anyway; you can reassign them, and it'll just generate a warning and happily change the value.

Ruby is a dynamic language, duck-typed language; you generally should not rely on the parser/interpreter to guarantee things like constantness for you.  There's no real benefit to scoping a constant, other than keeping your declaration near its use.  You could just move it up to a higher scope.  Another alternative that might make sense is to wrap your constants in a class/module to namespace them.  It's not exactly the same as a local constant, but it may clarify the code; it's hard to tell from your small example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it and it really doesn't make any sense. Your script seems *functional programming* oriented, in the sense that you declare a constant inside a function (which is really a method of the `main` object).

Thinking in a more object oriented way you *could* define that constant in the `Object` class (which will be inherited by `main`) making it accessible everywhere after that class extension:

```
class Object
    ABC = 123
    def foo( number ); return number * ABC; end
end
```

Or even better, if that particular constant only make sense in a specific class or module:

```
module/class Bar
    ABC = 123
    def foo( number ); return number * ABC; end
end
```